# OpenCart 3 - Show all products in a category from a manufacturer by direct URL

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

[ Using Opencart 3.x]

I'm trying to make a link in the main menu to list products from a manufacturer that belong to a certain category.

Because i couln't find anything manufacturer related in the category controller, i tried to do it by also creating a category for each manufacturer like the text below, and then combining them into a link.

**Manufacturers**

- **Sony**:

  manufacturer_id = 13
  manufacturer_category_id = 58
- **LG**

  manufacturer_id = 14
  manufacturer_category_id = 59

**Product category**

tv_category_id = 60

The link i tried:

```
    /index.php?route=product/category&path=59_60
```

But when i do this i get all the TV's from Sony, but also all the TV's from LG in the list.

Is there a way to do this right, so only all Sony TV's will be in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard controller to make a link **manufacturer && category**. You don't need to create category for each manufacturer.

But! There is a way using standard **OC3** **filters**.

1. *Catalog - Filters*. Here we creating filter, **Filter Group Name** "Manufacturer". Filter Values - "Manufacturer 1", "Manufacturer 2", ...(all your manufacturers). **Save**.
2. *Catalog - Categories*. **Edit** your category, which you would like to connect to manufacturer, i will call it "Your category". On the *Data* tab find **Filters**. Here, by entering first letters, select all filters ("Manufacturers" in your case), which you would line to link to this category. **Save**.
3. *Extensions - Extensions - Modules*. Find **Filter**, click **Install**, then **Edit**. On a filter module page set status "Enabled". **Save**.
4. *Design - Layout*. Find layout **Category**, click **Edit**. Add module **Filter** anywhere you want (for instance, under **Category** in *Column left*). **Save**.
5. **Catalog - Product**. Edit all product from a category you are working with. Editing the product, on the *Links* tab find **Filters**. Here, by entering first letters, select all one filter ("Manufacturer 1" in your case), which you would line to link to this product. **Save**.

That's all, go to "Your category" on the client side. There you will see a **Refine Search** module with the list of manufacturers. Check one of the manufacturers, click **Refine Search**. You will see the list on a products in "Your category" filtered by "Manufacturer 1". The URL is /index.php?route=product/category&path=58&filter=1. It's not a strict constant, if you adding new filters - order can be changed. But you can use it as a menu item link. Try. This should work.

Or you can use some other filter from [Opencart Marketplace](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=filter) which can generate filtered pages with constant URL.

Comment: Thanks @focus.style !! Works like a charm. Thanks for your great answer.

Comment: Pleasure to help you.